# DBD::Oracle install on 64 bit Ubuntu with instantclient 11.2

Tags: oracle, perl

So I have, what I *think* is a clean installation of the oracle instantclient for 64 bit ubuntu.

I've install the 4 modules: basic, sqlplus, jdbc and sdk.
I added a tnsnames.ora and the following items to my /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export ORACLE_ENV=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export PATH
```

When I try sqlplus, I get connectivity without a problem.

I've downloaded DBD::Oracle 1.74 and when I attempt to sudo -E perl Makefile.PL, I'm getting the most baffling error.

```
Using Oracle in /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's clearly got the directory in which my instant client and the libsqlplus.so reside, but it's not finding the file.

Suggestions?

I should add that sudo -E sqlplus gives a command not found error even though

sudo -E echo $PATH shows the :/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2 at the end of the PATH statement.
I can only run sqlplus as a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded the right package with sqlplus libraries included

From Oracle instant client website:
"SQL*Plus: Additional libraries and executable for running SQL*Plus with Instant Client"

Comment: If you read above, I'm pretty sure I've got all the right instant client bits. I downloaded, basic, sdk, sqlplus and jdbc and installed them all.

Comment: So, check inside "/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2" for libsqlplus.so. Is it there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how reusable this problem description will be for anyone else, but the short answer is: Installing DBD::Oracle using sudo, whether you're using sudo -i or sudo -E is pretty well bound to be problematic unless you have full control over the sudoers config.

Solution for my purposes was to run cpan and install truly as root.